# Taking a value from each line of a file to each their own var in php

Tags: php

Okay so if I had a text file named "user1.txt" and the contents are:

line 1 - John

line 2 - Doe

line 3 - 16

line 4 - Male

How could I make it so that each line has their separate var?

$firstname needs to have John

$lname -> Doe

$age -> 16

$gender -> Male

Sorry if it's a newbie question it's the first time im trying to do the file handling side of php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `file()` function in PHP to split each line of the file into an array then set each element of the array equal to it's respective variable. For example:

```
$lines = file('user1.txt');
$firstname = $lines[0];
$lname = $lines[1];
$age = $lines[2];
$gender = $lines[3];
```

Comment: ooh it's that simple? will it work if I do it in a word document?

Comment: @Xkajl, No it will not work with a word document because of how word documents are formatted. It will have to be a text document.

Comment: I seewell that's too bad

Answer (score 2):

```
list($firstname, $lname, $age, $gender) = file('user1.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$age = (int) $age; // Unfortunately casting inside `list` won't work
```

Comment: another way! Thanks!

Comment: @Xkajl this is compact, but @C.Liddell's answer has the advantage that you could also cast `$age` to integer with `$age = (int) $lines[2];`.

Comment: I see I thought you could do something like


list($firstname, $lname,(int) $age, $gender) = file('user1.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

or something like that

Comment: @Xkajl, that would throw a parse error. You should cast it after initial assignment.